# Cordova plugin not working (not defined)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using Phonegap and I want use this m
plugin: https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer

Unfortunelly console printed this information when I tried use this plugin:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: BTPrinter is not defined`

But if I used cmd and checked plugins: ...go to app folder and type `phonegap plugin list`
I see: `cordova-plugin-bluetooth-printer 0.0.1-dev "BluetoothPrinter"`

Do you know where can be problem?

confix.xml:

```
`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetooth-printer" />`
```

Thank you!

Comment: Depends a lot on how your build is setup. Most likely whatever process isn't copying the plugin src to the proper location, or your app that's actually running isn't looking in whatever spot the library exists.

Comment: I used Phonegap desktop aplication (just click on make new project).

Comment: App folder contains these subfolders: .cordova, hooks, platforms, plugins (contains bluetooth printer plugin), red, www, confix.xml

Comment: Have you added a platform android/ios to it?

Comment: just try removing current platform and adding a new platform(android/ios) and then reinstall the plugin.

Comment: @VítHellebrand Could you post your code that you used to invoke the plugin?

Comment: I think problem will be in config.xml. Plugin is installed but not added into config.xml automatically. Which part of code do you want post?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
If I try build via build.phonegap.com:

```
Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app): //github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git#1.0.0": support for subdirectories is deprecated and will be removed in Cordova@7 Fetching plugin "https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git" via git clone Cloning full repository Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git via git. Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect: Error: git: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: error: pathspec '1.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git. -
```